# How do you remotely BOF without knowing source code?

Tags: exploit

I have two questions.

Note that I have very basic understanding of how BOF works, but don't know the exact mechanism or anything beyond what an ordinary computer user knows.

My understanding of BOF is that for every program there's a bucket that can hold memories. Like, let's say there is an input A, and it can hold 16 letters.

And if you put 16 A's in there and then put a command after like:
A = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAsudo poweroff
and the computer should shutdown if it is found vulnerable. (or something similar, don't try to go too deep since I won't understand)

However, you don't know how much the bucket can hold. You should be able to know the size of the bucket if you've seen the source code, but if you intend to attack an unknown remote server, you shouldn't know anything about it, or even anything about what programs the server uses.

How do you find out how you should BOF without knowing the source code or any knowledge about the server?

And another question. How do you find inputs and send inputs to remote PC's? I've heard of famous worms like sasser or conficker, and apparently it sends some kind of codes to other PC's, but regular PC's shouldn't have any servers running. If they run servers, there might be some inputs that can be vulnerable to BOF, but how does regular PC's take malicious codes from online and get pwned?

I only want to understand how things work.

Comment: BOF = Buffer Overflow?

Comment: No offense, but I think it will be hard to explain how buffer overflows work because you have a basic misunderstanding of a few other things (like your talk of "buckets" and "inputs" and such isn't quite right) and also it requires a more fundamental knowledge of how programs are executed on typical processors (instruction pointers, call stacks, etc., and the string of bytes "sudo poweroff" doesn't really make sense there). Also the understanding of how a vulnerability can arise requires a bit of an understanding of typical programming techniques and how these mistakes can be made.

Comment: I.e. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MO0r930Sn_8

Comment: Moderators, the questioner appears to be asking about blind exploitation, a very-valid question -- http://repo.palkeo.com/repositories/mirror7.meh.or.id/expl0it/Blind%20Exploitation%20of%20Stack%20Overflow%20Vulnerabilities.pdf

Comment: @atdre Can you rewrite it to make it clearer? If so, might be worth giving that a try then submitting a reopen request.

Answer (score -1):

Your understanding of BOF is not accurate, i would suggest reading the exploitation chapter in [The Art of Exploitation](https://www.nostarch.com/hacking2.htm) to get better understanding .

Now regarding exploiting an application without knowing the source code , you can do this with a process called "Fuzzing" which involves sending variable length arbitrary data to where the application is expecting an input and monitor the app's reaction -using a debugger - (you will have to deploy the vulnerable 
app on a local machine first so you can develop your exploit ) 
Once you're exploitation code is finished, you can deploy the attack against the remote machine (assuming it's not protected with some protection mechanism such as ASLR )  .

Comment: Incorrect, it is you who does not understand (please don't be rude). Blind stack overflow brute-force techniques and tools have been around since 2005 -- http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/blind-buffer-overflows-isapi-extensions -- with updates in the last 5 years. Dave Aitel discusses more here -- http://seclists.org/dailydave/2005/q1/107